# jQuery - selecting an item does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make an extension that selects a shoe size, and hits the add to cart button on page load. I've done the latter, but selecting the shoe size does not work (I've tried selecting the `li` element). I'm assuming its more complicated than that but I havent been able to figure it out. [website](https://store.nike.com/ca/en_gb/pd/air-vapormax-running-shoe/pid-12022334/pgid-12082853)

Here's my code:

```
function addToCart() {
  $( "#buyingtools-add-to-cart-button" ).click();
}

function addSize() {
  if ($("select[name='skuAndSize']").length) {
    $("option[name='skuId']").click()
    alert($("option[name='skuId']").val())
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  addSize();
  addToCart();
  // alert("HELLO")
}
);
```

EDIT:

```
function addSize() {
  if ($("select[name='skuAndSize']").length) {
    $('div[class*=exp-pdp-size-dropdown-container] > ul > li:nth-child(3)').mouseup();
    alert($('div[class*=exp-pdp-size-dropdown-container] > ul > li').html());
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  addSize();
  // addToCart();
  // alert("HELLO")
}
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** (credit to Troy Wray) because you are writing a Chrome extension, you'll need to trigger the `mouseup` event using vanilla JS like so:

```
var mouseUpEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
mouseUpEvent.initEvent("mouseup", true, true);
​
var el = $("li.nsg-form--drop-down--option:nth-child(4)")[0];
el.dispatchEvent(mouseUpEvent);
```

======================

Answer below does not apply to Chrome extension:

Fiddled around with it and it looks like the dropdown is listening to the `mouseup` event as opposed to `click` event on the `li`, so you'll want to do something like this:

```
$(selectedLi).mouseup();
```

For example, something like this:

```
$("li.nsg-form--drop-down--option:nth-child(4)").mouseup(); // selects 8.5
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried running the code (edited) and it does not automatically select a size (this case it would be the first one), but when I click it manually, the alert fires. Am I missing something?

Comment: You have a small bug in your code. Don't pass a callback to `mouseup` as that will register an event handler for `mouseup` as opposed to triggering the `mouseup` event.

Comment: Also, it looks like you your selector is selecting all `li`s from the list. What you really want is to only select one. i.e. `$('div[class*=exp-pdp-size-dropdown-container] > ul > li:nth-child(3)').mouseup()`

Comment: Thanks, made changes according to your suggestions but it still does not select the size.. (although still fires the html alert). You got it to work on your end?

Comment: Seems to be working on my end. If you navigate to the webpage you provided and paste in the code `$("li.nsg-form--drop-down--option:nth-child(4)").mouseup();` on the chrome console -- does it not select size 8.5?

Comment: it does! However I've been working on this via a chrome extension but I dont see how it would work via the console directly but not via the script in the extension..

Comment: I think it's because the jquery in the content script cannot fire an event handler attached by jquery in the page (part of the deliberate scope isolation). I believe it will work if you use windows native event handlers.

Comment: Good call. What you need to do then is use vanilla JS to trigger the event. Unwrap the jQuery object and call onmouseup(). I’ll update answer.

Comment: Thanks! One more thing - How would you select all the elements that are the sizes, instead of selecting only one?

Comment: Remove the `:nth-child()` from the selector, and you'll get an array of all shoe-size `li`s